# Which prefix does NGINX use for "include"?

Tags: nginx

While I'm compiling NGINX, I get this message:

```
nginx path prefix:          "/tmp/app"
nginx binary file:          "/tmp/app/progs/nginx/sbin/nginx"
nginx configuration prefix: "/tmp/app/progs"
nginx configuration file:   "/tmp/app/progs/nginx.conf"
```

Does NGINX use the `path prefix` or the `configuration prefix` for `include` directives in `nginx.conf`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/installoptions/#) suggests that it's the "prefix path":

> –prefix=*path* defines a directory that will keep server files. **This same directory will also be used for all relative paths** set by configure (except for paths to libraries sources) and **in the nginx.conf configuration file**. It is set to the `/usr/local/nginx` directory by default.

By contrast:

> –conf-path=*path* sets the name of an `nginx.conf` configuration file. If needs be, NGINX can always be started with a different configuration file, by specifying it in the command-line parameter `-c file`. By default the file is named `prefix/conf/nginx.conf`.

However, [this is a documentation bug](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/781), and [your include paths will in fact be relative to the "config path"](http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2016-April/050456.html).

Comment: When I use `include  mime.types`, it uses the "configuration prefix", not the "path prefix".

Comment: @dgo.a: Then that's a bug, either in nginx or in the documentation. Ask the developers. Do they have a mailing list? And if you already knew the answer, why did you ask? lol

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Yes, they do have a mailing list: https://www.nginx.com/support/ (under Community Support). (However, I won't submit it. Someone more experienced would do a better job at it.)

Comment: @dgo.a: Nah, go for it! You're the one with the issue, so if they have follow-up questions or suggestions then you're the one who needs to be there to discuss them.

Comment: This is the answer I got from an NGINX dev in the mailing list (in case you would like to update your answer): http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2016-April/050456.html  "Configuration-specific paths like 
in the 'include' directive are resolved relative to the conf prefix, 
that is, relative to the directory where nginx.conf file resides."

Comment: @dgo.a: Please suggest to them that they clarify this in the documentation.

Comment: I'll try. It seems the change was added back in 2007 and documented in the CHANGE log. Odd it hasn't made it into the other docs in the past 8 yrs. You can read the rest of the thread: http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2016-April/050468.html

Comment: It seems they are already on the case: "This should be documented somewhere, and we already have a ticket 
for a related question, https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/781 "